# Hypothesis Testing help

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Really have no idea where to start :(

In an experiment comparing two weight-loss regimes A and B 20 test subjects were matched into 10 pairs so that within each pair the subjects were as similar as possible. Then A was randomly allocated to one of the subjects in each pair, and then B allocated to the other. The number of kilograms lost for each person is obtained and then the ordered A−B differences for each pair (in kg) are given below in
the object d, together with some summary statistics:

> sort(d)
>   [1] -0.9 -0.3 0.2 0.4 0.6 1.2 1.4 3.3 3.5 4.3
>
> mean(d)
>   [1] 1.37
>
> sd(d)
>   [1] 1.755025

By specifying and checking (with a boxplot) an appropriate normality assumption perform a formal hypothesis test of H0:“regimes the same” against H1:“regimes not the same”.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You might consider a $t$-test

Comment: Why did you delete nearly all your post and changed the tags to phony ones? If your aim was to cover your tracks, you should know that this kind of behaviour is not well regarded on the site.

Comment: Your second try to mask the question (cleverer than the first one) made me curious. So, you are trying to hide that you copied verbatim the question from [this Chegg study question](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/experiment-comparing-two-weight-loss-regimes-b-20-test-subjects-matched-10-pairs-within-pa-q5789139). Why is that?

Comment: Once the question has been asked and answered, please **do not** significantly alter it. You may _improve_ it (please do, in fact), but otherwise the meaning of the question should stay intact.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some steps and rationale:

1. Make a box plot. You can do a rough check of normality by verifying that the upper and lower quartiles are approximately 0.7 standard deviations from the mean and that extreme outliers are less than 4 standard deviations from the mean. The box plot should look symmetric.
2. If the data appear normal, then calculate the t-statistic: $T=\frac{\bar X}{S}$, where we are assuming the mean difference will be zero.
3. Look up the T-value in a t-distribution table (using 9 degrees of freedom) at 0.05 significance, call this $\pm K$

If your |T|>|K|, reject the null.